# TO-263S heat dissipation

Tags: mosfet, pcb, pcb-design, heat, heatsink

I'm designing a mosfet PWM device with a rather high current. According to my LTspice simulation the mosfet has an average power dissipation of 20W. The mosfet had a TO-263S package ( https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/mosfet/r6020pnjfratl-e.pdf ). What would be the best setup/design to get rid of this heat? I have two of those mosfets next to each other, so the heat sink should be able to dissipate 40W. Can i just connect the heat sink to the top of the case or are there better alternatives?

EDIT: Datasheet talks about a maw PD of 305W, how can this ever be dissipated out of such a package? Are there special tricks to do so?

Comment: The best TO-263 heatsink I've seen ([this one](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/303/sink_d-1265548.pdf)) is 5.6 degC/watt. So 20 watts means a temperature rise of 112 degC and very little headroom especially when the device itself is 0.4 degC/watt so, realistically it will warm by 120 degC and, in a controlled ambient of 25 the max temp is 145 degC. But even this won't account for local ambient heating of another 10, 20 or 30 deg. The MOSFET junction max temperature is 150 degC so, IMHO, wrong device package for your application without extensive fanning.

Comment: I started a proper answer for this and it was both too long, too vague, and had me hitting the books too hard.  Do a search on "thermal management for surface mount devices".  There's a *lot* of information out there on the web.  Basically, you need to get the heat from the FETs to the board, from the top of the board to the bottom (with **lots** of thermal vias), from the bottom of the board to a heat sink (with gap pad material, probably), and from the heat sink to the air.  Expect to do a lot of work, and expect to either need a fan, or an external heat sink as big as a paperback book.

Comment: [This site](https://celsiainc.com/resources/calculators/heat-sink-size-calculator/) is helpful for once you get the heat off the board and onto a heat sink.

Comment: Oh -- **and** expect that you'll want to use thicker copper than the typical 0.5 or 1oz that you get if you don't ask for anything special.  You'll be trading off the minimum feature size for copper thickness, but the power levels you're considering imply at least 2oz copper, if not 4 or 8 (so, no 0.5mm pitch packages on that board!)

Comment: @TimWescott PCB will be 2oZ of copper. I'm thinking about a large copper pour with thermal via's and connect a heatsink to this pad. Although i have no experience with such heatsinks and i don't know what is the best solution to attach this to the copper pour

Comment: Look for "gap pad" (or "thermal pad", brand name "Silpad").  It's got pretty high thermal conductivity, and conforms to the wiggles in the PCB surface.

Comment: WRT your edit, datasheets will often list some specs tolerable in "pulse" situations. The device might be able to deal with 304W during a few milliseconds/microseconds, not necessarily continuously.

Answer (score 2):

Surface-mount devices, in general, use a different method of heatsinking from through-hole ones.

You'll notice that one of the terminals of your TO-263 (also called D²PAK, incidentally) package is a very large tab on the back, unlike the others. This tab is bonded tightly to the die, and intended to be used as a heatsink.

What you do for this is use a large copper fill on your PCB (I'm not personally familiar with the calculations that go into how to size it), and use that as your heatsink. You can via-stitch this to a large fill on the other side of the board too, for additional power dissipation. The copper conducts both electric current and heat, and can fairly effectively radiate it out to the surrounding air.

If this still isn't enough, you *can* get extruded heatsinks intended to be mounted to such a copper fill, but generally if you're thinking of doing that, you may want to consider a different package.

Comment: Unlikely that copper fills alone would be able to dissipate 20W.

Comment: @WesleyLee It is a lot to ask, but I expect it could be done with sufficiently thick copper (though you may be looking at 3 or 4 ounce copper, which gets expensive fast), a very large pad, and the via stitching I mentioned. Still, this isn't an application where I'd use a D²PAK; I'd look for a TO-220 or TO-247 variant that can be mounted to an extruded heatsink.

Comment: I know copper fills and via stitching is a common technique to do so. But i don't think it will be able to dissipate 40W( 2 mosfets close to each other). I'm pretty sure i will need a heatsink but i have no idea on how to have a good heat conductive connection between mosfets and heat sink?

Comment: @MichielReyntjens As I told Wesley, I would recommend you look for a different package, or a different part if you can. Surface-mount heatsinks can be bonded to the copper fill, but that seems like more trouble than it's worth, at least to me.

Comment: [SMD thermal jumpers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3RhWuXFixU) could help move that heat further away.

Comment: @WesleyLee Actually, the more I think about it the more I think you're probably right. I didn't give this a lot of thought about the actual amount of power involved, especially with two adjacent devices. I'll leave this answer here, but I might edit it once I get back from work.

Comment: I've had "fun" experiences with heavy copper, copper filled vias, thin multilayer PCBs attached to aluminum housings with custom cut thermal pads so I had a feeling 20W (+20W) was gonna be a bit challenging. Depending on the density of OPs layout he can consider Alu PCBs(single layer) or similar. Or turning the FETs on faster :P

Comment: Two datasheet entries that will help guide you in your selection of a replacement part (the one you have now isn't ideal) are the RthJA, which is the thermal resistance between the junction and ambient, and the absolute maximum junction temperature Tj.  RthJA is listed at 80C/W when mounted on a reasonably sized pad.  20W of heat generation will therefore produce a 1600C rise.  Yes, you could play around with copper weight and pad sizes but it's not going to drop temperature the two orders of magnitude you'd need to keep it from frying.  Like @Hearth said something in a TO-220 would be better.

Comment: There's a nice little chart on page 8 of this datasheet: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDB070AN06_F085-D.PDF that shows the RthJA relation to pad area for a 1oz board.  If you want to plan for a hot day of 35C, your thermal resistance needs to be in the area of ~5C/W (and should really be significantly less).  The chart shows that you're barely under 30 even with 10 square inches of copper.

Comment: @vir I think you might be abusing the data sheet somewhat in your previous comment. RthJA is the parallel heat removal path to the regular 0.41 degC/W heatsinking path.

Comment: @Andyaka we might be saying the same thing two ways.  RthJC is incorporated in RthJA with the RthCA indirectly specified on most datasheets as a copper pad of a given area and thickness at a certain ambient temperature.

Comment: @user263983 how do you get 5W from 0.25R and 20A? 100W surely.

Comment: @ Brian drummond Thanks. You right

Answer (score 0):

Standard copper foil (1 ounce per square foot, the thickness of 35 microns or 1.4 mils) has thermal resistance of 70 degree C per square.

If the footprint is 1 square cm (0.4" on a side), then a 3 by 3 grid gets you to 1.2" square, with thermal resistance additional of 70/8 = 9 degree C temperature rise.

At 40 watts, the rise is 360 degree C.

Just to spread the heat out to 1.2 square inches.

I think you should plan on using a different package.

Answer (score 0):

The TO-263 package can be advantageous e.g. for high frequency switiching due to lower parasitic inductance compared to the common TO-247 package. Also, space or part requirements can restrict the package choice.

For SMDs, the heat is usually transported to the other side of the PCB using thermal vias and the heatsink is connected on that side. For high power dissipation like in your case, thermal vias might not be sufficient for the heat transport to the other side of the PCB. In that case, it might be an option to use copper coins or inlays which are basically massive copper blocks instead of vias. 20W of power dissipation should be within the realms of possibility with such a solution.

A nice article about this topic can be found here: [High efficient heat dissipation on printed circuit boards](https://www.beam-verlag.de/app/download/29611792/HF-Praxis+1-2018+VII.pdf)

Regarding your edit, those 304W power dissipation are possible if you can manage 25°C case temperature. It's rather theoretical. It is basically calculated directly from Rthjc and the maximum junction temperature e.g. 304W*0.41°C/W+25°C=150°C

You could think of extreme measures like liquid (nitrogen) cooling to make such an insane power dissipation at least a little realistic.